# Calling variables in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

so at first i was reading about `plt.subplot()` in matplotlib and got into a problem. if i get a number of numpy arrays and want to use `.subplot()` within a for loop, how can i call each array and use it in `.subplot()` ?

Here's what i mean in code :

```py
# i have a number of arrays, x_i, which i is in the range of [1, 100]

def F(x) :
    return (np.cos(x) + np.tan(x**0.5))

# Wrong approach 
for i in range(1, 101) : 
    plt.subplot(25, 4, i)
    plt.plot(x_i, F(x_i), '-o')
```

suppose you have a number of variables. and you want to call them in a loop that contain the **same pattern** for names. How can you do that?

```py
# my variables are x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_100
def F(x) : 
    pass

# I want to perform an action on the x_i (e.g. call F function on it) in each loop
for i in range(100) : 
    F(x_i)
```

- i know the main use of lists is exactly what i said, but what if my variables aren't added to the lists. Am i supposed to add them to a list and then call `enumerate()` on the list?

Comment: You don't want variable x_1, x_2, ... and then try to construct a variable name from that string.  That doesn't work.  "x_i" is just a variable named "x_i" and changing "i" doesn't affect "x_i" at all.  
You want a list x = [x_1_value, x_2_value, ...], now x[0] gives you x_1_value.  Note python lists use zero based indexing.

Comment: PSA: **DON'T** have piles of variables. **DO** have *data structures*, like an array. `x_1` should be `x[0]`, etc. Using an array means you can do `for v in x:` and then `F(v)` with near zero fuss.

Comment: Hmm..., having 100 variables `x_1` to `x_100` is already a code smell... You'd better store them in a Python list (more or less `x = [x_1, ...x_100]` or use a 2D numpy array if they have all the same size.

Comment: Although you're not required to follow any particular style guide, adhering to [common practices](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) makes your code more readable.

Comment: It may be reasonable to use different variables for different plots if they are coming from different sources and expressing different things. You use a list when you want to do the same thine to a bunch of values. So, if the original data is derived differently, multiple variables is okay. If you then want to plot them all the same, put them in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to everyone who commented. it seems that the best approach is to ***store all the variables in an array*** (python list, numpy array, etc.) and then use indexing `arr[i]`.

any other approach would have lots of approach and is considered to be un-readable.

---

also as @tadman mentioned, checkout [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) for styling guide in python

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely do what the commenters are suggesting and use a singular list of your arrays or a dictionary or some other data structure so you don't have to use dynamically generated variable names.

That being said, if you must indulge in Python degeneracy, we can use the `exec` function, which does a literal execution of its string argument. **Don't do this.**

```
# Absolutely still the wrong approach
for i in range(1, 5) : 
    plt.subplot(25, 4, i)
    command = f"plt.plot(x_{i}, F(x_{i}), '-o')"
    exec(command)
```

Comment: `locals()[f"x_{i}"]` is preferable to `exec`, in my opinion. Although an array is absolutely the right solution